# Rabbit SSL configuration not working-{ssl_upgrade_error,{tls_alert,"certificate unknown"}}

Tags: java, erlang, rabbitmq, redhat, amqp

I have two servers where rabbit mq is running and are clustered. I have a CA signed certificate and this is configured on both the servers. One of the servers is up and running, but the other server give certificate unknown error.

I am really puzzled why the same set of certificates work on one server and not on the other.

```
[

  {rabbit, [
     {ssl_listeners, [ 5671]},
     {ssl_options, [{cacertfile,               "/etc/rabbitmq/certificates/RootCA.crt.pem"},
                        {certfile,             "/etc/rabbitmq/certificates/sserver_cert.pem"},
                        {keyfile,              "/etc/rabbitmq/certificates/server_key.pem"},
 {depth, 2},
                        {verify,verify_none},
                        {fail_if_no_peer_cert, false}]}
   ]}
].
```

**Rabbit MQ and Erlang Versions**

```
{erlang_version,
     "Erlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:30] [kernel-poll:true]\n"},

 [{rabbitmq_management,"RabbitMQ Management Console","3.5.3"},
      {rabbitmq_web_dispatch,"RabbitMQ Web Dispatcher","3.5.3"},
      {webmachine,"webmachine","1.10.3-rmq3.5.3-gite9359c7"},
      {mochiweb,"MochiMedia Web Server","2.7.0-rmq3.5.3-git680dba8"},
      {rabbitmq_management_agent,"RabbitMQ Management Agent","3.5.3"},
      {rabbit,"RabbitMQ","3.5.3"},
```

The error I am getting on one of the server:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 10-May-2016::20:21:52 ===
SSL: certify: ssl_alert.erl:92:Fatal error: certificate unknown

=ERROR REPORT==== 10-May-2016::20:21:52 ===
Error on AMQP connection <0.27744.2>:
{ssl_upgrade_error,{tls_alert,"unexpected message"}}

=ERROR REPORT==== 10-May-2016::20:21:52 ===
SSL: certify: ssl_alert.erl:92:Fatal error: unexpected message

=ERROR REPORT==== 10-May-2016::20:21:52 ===
Error on AMQP connection <0.27748.2>:
{ssl_upgrade_error,{tls_alert,"unexpected message"}}

=ERROR REPORT==== 10-May-2016::20:21:52 ===
SSL: certify: ssl_alert.erl:92:Fatal error: unexpected message

=ERROR REPORT==== 10-May-2016::20:21:53 ===
Error on AMQP connection <0.27752.2>:
{ssl_upgrade_error,{tls_alert,"certificate unknown"}}

=ERROR REPORT==== 10-May-2016::20:21:53 ===
SSL: certify: ssl_alert.erl:92:Fatal error: certificate unknown
```

Comment: What are permissions for *.pem files? Are the servers exactly the same?

Comment: The servers are same, build using the puppet script.chmod 777 permission is given to all *pem files.

Comment: The error message starting with `ssl_alert.erl:92` shows that the _client_ sent a fatal alert with the description "certificate unknown". Perhaps the client verifies the server hostname against what's in the certificate, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I've had nothing but pain trying to get rabbit to work with TLS.

As an alternative, we finally ended up using stunnel (https://www.stunnel.org/index.html) and creating transparent tunneled connections on the client and server side.

It actually worked rather well, as it had the added development benefit of not needing to change the client code, just the network address to which they connected.